# WPF Core App crashes on writing data to Access DB due to Office 365 auto-login

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, office365, oledb

In my C# WPF Core application, using OLEDBConnection, I am able to read data from my Access database without being connected to the same network which contains my SharePoint site.  My objective is to write data to the Access DB while not connected to the network, then synchronize at a later point which I am connected to the network.  Below is the AccessViolationException caused by Office 365 trying to connect. [image: WPf Access error]

The issue is not the OLEDBConnection.  I am able to read successfully from the DB and my SQL is generated successfully on the updates.  How can I work around this Sharepoint automatic login functionality in order to write to my access DB (but not synchronizing to the master DB)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you attempting to use oleDB to connect to a local Access database, but that database is NOT really ONLY local, but is connected and synced to SharePoint. And the logon on parts, the sync parts, and the off line mode, the on-line mode is ALL PART of Access and NOT just oleDB.

In other words:
You need to write your application in Access if you want to free-load off of all those fancy extra parts like the SharePoint logon, and the Access sync to tables and all that fancy stuff that is part of Access.

If you going to use .net? Then the .net application has to hit the SharePoint web services and use + consume the SharePoint lists directly - not have Access do all that extra cool work. .net has all of the abilities to hit SharePoint, and the web service calls can be REST, but I think most are in fact SOAP calls. (but SOAP and a WSDL for SharePoint is well documented and supported).

If you need a off-line, then on-line sync system? Then you have to roll your own, or use the depreciated sync framework for.net (it is depreciated, but can still be used. And there is/are sync providers for SharePoint. So, you could still have a local accDB (Access data file), but the data tables would not be linked to SharePoint. Your .net application will have to do the sync stuff.

You trying to hit the tables via oleDB, but you THEN want all that SharePoint logon, and all that VERY WAY COOL SharePoint sync stuff built into Access (which is NOT just part of the database engine and oleDB, but is bits and parts that belong to Access.).

You could consider and attempt to automate a WHOLE running copy of Access. But then again, you would not be using oleDB anymore, but in fact just like you can create a instance of Word, or Excel or say Outlook in .net? You would thus be creating a full running copy of Access.

Keep in mind that Access as a COM object does not really correctly expose the off-line, on-line and sync options with a nice set of clean methods and properties. I know this to be the case, since even from VBA, you can't really control the off-line mode vs the on-line mode. What you can do is "test" and "know" if you are currently disconnected. You can then execute a refresh tables command.

```
VBA:
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefreshSharePointList
```

However, the above will then attempt to refresh, and if the user is off line, the app will remain off line, but WILL tell the user. The user is THEN given this option:

[image]

So, they have to click on this option. Once they then re-connect, then they will see this:

[image]

So, the above acCmdRefreshSharePointList ONLY really triggers a full refresh (and sync) of data AFTER the user has cliced on the UI above. Unfortunately, to my knowledge the UI is the the ONLY way to for the user to deal with the SharePoint connected, or not (you can test/check in VBA, but you can't control it). Once the user as per above has re-connected, then then you can force a refresh as per above command, but it really don't help a lot, since you can't toggle or control the off/line or on/line mode from VBA (and thus via COM object automation from .net you can't either).

So the the meat and parts you need to control the logon etc. is part of Access and NOT part of the oleDB object model.

As noted, even the Access model does not expose the control of the off/line and on-line mode in a useful way. But it better then what you have from .net.

If you using .net? The as noted, hit the SharePoint web services to inter-act with the lists, and if you need a local off-line mode, then you have to roll your own sync system, or use the .net sync framework.